# dpkg was interuppted

Tags: dpkg

I tried to install Times New Roman font on my Ubuntu. I used this code formulation: sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts. Everything looked fine, until the screen showed a kind of agreement statement. I tried to enter the 'OK' there, but it didn't work. So, I thought the process of installing the font is done. Then, I restarted the computer. But, the font, I could find it in my Libreoffice. I wrote the same formulation again for installing it. But I got this notification:

```
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Can somebody help me to fix this? Thanks

Comment: @herry run `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and accept the licensing during install using TAB key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` in a terminal. Restart/reboot may be necessary.

If you received any errors after running both commands, post them as a comment in this answer.

Comment: It works. I have the times new roman in my libreoffice. Thanks.